# What is "Redefined from long to double" meaning in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

I read Javascript document to know [MouseEvent.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX).

[image]

I can't understand when and why use "Redefined from long to double". Does clientX always return long type?

Comment: it's a long (or integer) in all browsers, except Chrome, which follows the redefined standard according to the link given on that page - https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-mouseevent-clientx - it's for subpixel precision - similar to the changes in `window.scroll[XY]` which are now float instead of integer

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I get double type clientX value? I use Chrome 60 but it returns always long type.

Comment: I guess it depends on your operating system and display device capabilities ... don't concern yourself about it, javascript in reality has only one numeric type, and that is `Number` which is a 64bit floating point float - the reason why `.clientX` was `redefined` from long integer to double float was purely for such combinations of hardware that has the concept of sub-pixel precision