# How to get Decimal values of x y coordinates on mouse Move in Typescript Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mouseevent

I am converting my UI From Flash/Flex and it saves values in decimal in Flex UI. I have to reuse those values.

I have created an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhtiau) for my issue. Excerpt:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div (mousemove)="showXY($event)"></div>`,
  styles: [`div { border: 1px solid black; height: 500px; width: 500px }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  x: number;
  y: number;
  showXY(e: MouseEvent) {
    this.x = e.offsetX;
    this.y = e.offsetY;
    console.log('x: ', this.x, 'y: ', this.y);
  }
}
```

I want to see decimal precision of x and y values on mouse move over the div how can I do that ?

Comment: @msanford I am converting my UI From Flash/Flex and it saves values in decimal in Flex UI. i have to reuse those values

Comment: Do you need to support browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: @msanford nope only Chrome latest version

Comment: I deleted my original, incorrect assertion that offsetX/Y are always integers and offered a possible (though probably unsatisfying) solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my astonishment, `MouseEvent.offset{X,Y}` are *[supposed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX#Return_value)* to be represented by double-precision floating-point numbers, though I have never seen or used them in the wild:

> Return Value
>
> A **double** floating point value. Early versions of the spec defined
>   this as an **integer**. See the Browser compatibility section for
>   details.

The compatibility chart claims that Chrome 56 onward changed their internal representation to a double.

According to [comments on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853661/what-is-redefined-from-long-to-double-meaning-in-javascript), you may be able to acquire sub-pixel resolution, but that seems to be *dependent on hardware*. For example, my current setup (simple 1080p Benq LCD monitor on Windows 10) doesn't offer subpixel resolution, so the values are returned as integers.

So you'll have to account for this when porting your application, and assume that subpixel resolution is a feature offered under progressive enhancement - in what seems to be fairly rare cases at that - and `Math.floor()` / `.ceil()` your values otherwise.

I suppose you could detect sub-pixel capability by simply [looking for a decimal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) in the return value (i.e., `Number.isInteger(MouseEvent.offsetX)`).